# How do I disable flutter_chart selection?

Tags: flutter

Anyone knows how to disable the chart selection in Flutter?

I'm referring this library which's the most popular chart library in Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your `flutter_chart`'s widget (sorry I never used it on my own, so not sure widget name) in `AbsorbPointer` widget

```
AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: true, // disable selection 
  child: YourChartWidget(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works great but it doesn't meet my needs. The reason I wanted to disable the chart's selection is to enable other selection on top of it but AbsorbPointer makes the area totally unselectable